# Check and insert into elasticsearch using java api

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can I insert a data into a index in elasticsearch using java api in the most efficient way  .First I need to check if the entry exists using a field lets say log_id ,if it exists that I will update that entry else i will insert a new entry into elasticsearch .Is there any method in elasticsearch which does both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in BULK ( if you are doing insert and update in bulk) Following is a simple example :

check if the `log_id` exists already:

if existing create Update json string `\n` should be there,

```
{ "update" : {"_id" : "1", "_type" : "type1", "_index" : "index1"} }\n{ "doc" : {"field2" : "value2"} }
```

else create a Insert Json like below `\n` should be there,

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }\n{ "field1" : "value1" }
```

Have them in list and do the `BULK API`.